# How we may express four squares whose difference is each a square in terms of (preferably solid) geometry?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, solid-geometry, pythagorean-triples

The problem of finding four squares whose difference is each a square is much more exhaustive as I thought. A quest up to $2^{34}$ yields nothing. The largest almost solution found in the range up to $2^{34}$ is $(w,x,y,z)=(17155833660,17162453700,17170527465,17177153175)$ and with Arty's tool we are still searching.

***My Question:***
Can we express this problem in terms of a solid geometry such as for example 4D-polyhedra, polychoron or [5-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell#/media/File:5-cell.gif) or are there connections to Coxeter Groups? I am looking for (preferably solid) geometric or geometric algebraic ways to describe the following system of diophantine equations:

\begin{array}{lllllll}
z^2-y^2&=&\square_1&\qquad\qquad&y^2-x^2&=&\square_4\\
z^2-x^2&=&\square_2&\qquad\qquad&y^2-w^2&=&\square_5\\
z^2-w^2&=&\square_3&\qquad\qquad&x^2-w^2&=&\square_6
\end{array}

***What I tried so far:***
I first tried my hand at the simpler version, the three squares variant. Here we are able to describe the problem of finding three squares whose difference is each a square using  a ***cuboid having one face diagonal irrational*** with the following system of diophantine equations:

\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=d_{bc}^2\qquad c^2+a^2=d_{ac}^2\qquad a^2+b^2+c^2=d_{abc}^2
\end{equation}

The notation above reuses MathWorld's variables/nomenclature that has been utilized for describing a ["Perfect Cuboid"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectCuboid.html). The squares of $d_{abc}$, $d_{ac}$, $c$ and of $d_{abc}$, $d_{bc}$, $b$ have their differences square and therefore provide solutions for three squares whose difference is each a square:

\begin{equation*}
{
\begin{array}{lllllllll}
d_{abc}^2&-d_{ac}^2&=&b^2&\hspace{2em}\qquad&d_{abc}^2&-d_{bc}^2&=&c^2\\
d_{abc}^2&-c^2&=&d_{bc}^2&\hspace{2em}\qquad&d_{abc}^2&-b^2&=&d_{ac}^2\\
d_{ac}^2&-c^2&=&a^2&\hspace{2em}\qquad&d_{bc}^2&-b^2&=&a^2
\end{array}}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Do you have examples of three squares whose differences in pairs are all squares?

Comment: Yes - I collected such triples up to 12 millions (and more). Please take a look at [this CSV file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sultanow/pythagorean/main/data/pythagorean_12000000.csv). The first, third and last number forms such a triple. For example: `[153,185,697]` or `[4193475,9569725,10490875]`.

Comment: In order to provide a larger triple, you may use `[17178011760,17178310716,17178314275]` or take out values from the "almost solution" given in the question.

Comment: Problem D18 in Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, 3rd edition, it titled, "Is there a perfect cuboid? Four squares whose sums in pairs are square. Four squares whose differences are square." Of the differences problem, Guy writes, "Although a solution is unlikely, there do not appear to be any congruence conditions which forbid it."

Comment: Thank you for this interesting hint. Does this means: finding four squares whose difference each is again a square is equivalent to finding a perfect cuboid?

Comment: No. After discussing the perfect cuboid, Guy weakens it to the problem where one face diagonal is irrational. Then he represents solutions to that weaker problem by a graph, and then he says that if that graph has a certain kind of subgraph you get four squares with square differences. So I don't think there's a simple implication in either direction between the four squares problem and the rational cuboid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have positive integers satisfying
\begin{array}{lllllll}
z^2-y^2&=&a^2&\qquad\qquad&y^2-x^2&=&d^2\\
z^2-x^2&=&b^2&\qquad\qquad&y^2-w^2&=&e^2\\
z^2-w^2&=&c^2&\qquad\qquad&x^2-w^2&=&f^2
\end{array}
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
b^2&=&z^2-x^2=(z^2-y^2)+(y^2-x^2)=a^2+d^2,\\
c^2&=&z^2-w^2=(z^2-y^2)+(y^2-w^2)=a^2+e^2,\\
e^2&=&y^2-w^2=(y^2-x^2)+(x^2-w^2)=d^2+f^2,
\end{eqnarray*}
and so the system above is equivalent to
\begin{array}{lllllll}
z^2&=&a^2+y^2&\qquad\qquad&y^2&=&d^2+x^2\\
b^2&=&a^2+d^2&\qquad\qquad&e^2&=&d^2+f^2\\
c^2&=&a^2+e^2&\qquad\qquad&x^2&=&f^2+w^2
\end{array}
We can reorder these equations a bit, and substitute to express them all in terms of $a$, $d$, $f$ and $w$, to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
b^2&=&a^2+d^2\\
e^2&=&d^2+f^2\\
x^2&=&f^2+w^2\\
c^2&=&a^2+d^2+f^2\\
y^2&=&d^2+f^2+w^2\\
z^2&=&a^2+d^2+f^2+w^2
\end{eqnarray*}
This can be interpreted as a $4$-dimensional cuboid with integer sides having three (particular!) integer face diagonals, two (particular!) integer solid diagonals, and integer 'long' diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to find four tuples where the difference between adjacent squares is also a square.

$$(9,\space 25,\space 169,\space 7225)\\ 
(16,\space 25,\space 169,\space 7225)\\ 
(49,\space 625,\space 4225,\space 9409)\\ 
(81,\space 225,\space 625,\space 4225)$$

It is much more difficult (if not impossible) to have the difference between all of these squares be a square.

Here is a sample of almost correct square combos.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n_1& d_{1,2} & n_2 & d_{1,3} & d_{2,3} & n_3   & d_{1,4} & d_{2,4}   & d_{3,4}  & n_4   \\ \hline
520^2& 117^2& 533^2& 765^2& 756^2& 925^2& ? & 3444^2& 3360^2& 3485^2\\ \hline
756^2& 117^2& 765^2& 533^2& 520^2& 925^2&  ? & 3400^2& 3360^2& 3485^2\\ \hline
1040^2& 234^2& 1066^2& 1530^2& 1512^2& 1850^2& ? & 6888^2& 6720^2& 6970^2\\ \hline
1428^2& 1771^2& 2275^2& 3179^2& 2640^2& 3485^2&  ? & 3828^2& 2772^2& 4453^2\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

[Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem#:%7E:text=Lagrange%27s%20four%2Dsquare%20theorem%2C%20also,additive%20basis%20of%20order%20four.&text=This%20theorem%20was%20proven%20by%20Joseph%20Louis%20Lagrange%20in%201770.)
states that any natural number can be the sum of $\space 4\space$ squares but the difference $\space d_{1,4}\space $ is  the sum of
$\quad d_{1,2} + n_2 + d_{2,3} + n_3 + d_{3,4}\quad$
and there are exceptions to natural numbers being
[the sum of $\space 5 $-or-more squares](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Will-MMz-201037918.pdf).

It says that, "An integer $\space n ≥ 34 \space$ can be written as a sum of $\space k\space $ positive squares for all k satisfying $\space 5 ≤ k ≤ n \space $ except for
$\space k = n − 13, n − 10, n − 7,
n − 5, n − 4, n − 2, n − 1."\quad $
Since $\space k= 5,\space$ there is no solution for
$\space d_{1,4}=n_4-n_1.$