# Let $w<x$ be integers with $x^2-w^2$ beeing a square. If no $y$ exists with $y^2-x^2$, $y^2-w^2$ being squares, can we show no $y$ exists for $nw<nx$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

There exist vast pairs $(w,x)$, $w<x$ with $x^2-w^2=\square_1$ beeing a square (also known as *Pythagorean Triples*). I am trying to distinguish two "classes" of such pairs:

- Those pairs for which **no** $y$ exists that satisfies $y^2-x^2=\square_2$, $y^2-w^2=\square_3$ being again perfect squares. In the plot below these pairs are colored red. Some examples of such "useless pairs" are $(4,5),(8,10),(24,26)$.
- Those pairs for which a $y$ exists satisfying that condition. These pairs are the green dots in the chart below. Some examples of such "promising pairs" are $(153,185),(264,520),(264,561)$.

When taking a look at this plot I came to the ***question:*** In the case we know that for a pair $(w,x)$ no such $y$ exists with $y^2-x^2$, $y^2-w^2$ being squares, can we formally show that no $y$ exist for any pair $(n\cdot w,n\cdot x)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

***Background and ideas:***
With Arty we implement and run a program searching for triples $(w,x,y)$ and even quadruples $(w,x,y,z)$ whose difference of squared elements produce again squares.

We could speed up our search by being able to distiguish "useless pairs" (those pairs for which we will not find an integer $y$ completing the pair to a triple whose difference of squared elements produce again squares) from "promising pairs" (those ones for which an integer $y$ exists).

Another idea was to use a *DecisionTreeClassifier* who tries to distinguish between "useless pairs" (red dots in the plot) and "promising pairs" (green dots) based on the slope $\frac{x}{w}$. This classifier achieved an accuracy of $0.9065$ (thee this [notebook at GitHub](https://github.com/Sultanow/pythagorean/blob/main/notebook/cluster_pairs.ipynb)).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\space w^2 + x^2 =y^2\space$ to work, when
$\space (w,x,y)\space$
are divided by
$\space g=GCD(w,x,y),\space$
then the first two terms must be of opposite parity so that the third can be odd. If both are the same parity, then the third term will be even, no matter what the multiplier.
Since $\space GCD(153,185)=1,\space$ and the terms are both odd, no $\space y$-value can exist for them no matter what the multiplier.

In another example, your
$\space  (264,520)=8\times(33,65)\space$ so the same is true; neither can yield a $\space y$-value that, when multiplied by the $\space GCD.\space$ completes a valid triple.

We can find $\space 3 \space$ squares  whose differences are all squares but not $\space 4\space $  as shown for your previous questions
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384319/let-wx-be-integers-with-x2-w2-beeing-a-square-which-condition-they-must/4387290#4387290)
and
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375353/how-we-may-express-four-squares-whose-difference-is-each-a-square-in-terms-of-p/4375851#4375851).

Comment: Great - thank you very much for your short proof! The fact that no quadruple exists may be a bit more tricky. It is a still open number theory problem for which no proof and no counter proof exist, see for example Gerry Myerson comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4375353/993738)

Comment: Probably you have a typo - instead of `GCD(x, y, z)` you probably meant `GCD(w, x, y)`?

Comment: @Arty Yes, I made a typo, corrected, thanks. As for the quadruple thing. The problem is that $\space n_4 -n_1\space$ must be the sum of five squares and this may not be possible. Read about "Sums of 5 or more positive squares" in 
[this](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Will-MMz-201037918.pdf) paper.

Comment: @poetasis: Thanks again for your counterexample given in your answer. Let us just complete the "promising" pairs as follows: $(264,520,1105)$ and $(153,185,697)$. Since we cannot find a $y$ for the pair $(33,65)$ but for the multiple $(8\cdot33,8\cdot65)=(264,520)$, we have no chance to conclude the existence/non-existence of a $y$ from one pair to a multiple of this pair - right?

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow  I was right in my conclusion that no such triples could have the same multiple of components but, if different multiples are allowed for each term, we have, for example.  
$\space 1105 = 5\times13\times17.\quad $
$\space 520 = 5\times13.\quad $
The pertinent triples where $\space y=1105\space $ are

$$
f(24,23)=(47,1104,1105)\\ 
f(31,12)=(817,744,1105)\\ 
f(32,9)=(943,576,1105)\\ 
f(33,4)=(1073,\large{264}\small,1105)\\ 
65\times f(4,1)=65\times (15,8,17)=(975,\large{520}\small,1105)\quad 
$$

Comment: @Eldar Sultanow   $\quad$I meant that
$\space 520=5\times8\times 13\space =65\times 8\quad$ but you picked up on that subconsciously didn't you? No need to acknowledge; if we comment too much, they'll move us to a chat room. :(